# how to set video file as public in google drive and how to determine when finished processing ? using php

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to create a PHP function that when a file path is given and also a folder name
it will upload the file (99.9% of the time is video) and give me the link back.

I have managed to do all of these steps, the only problem is before going forward I noticed that I need to make the file public, also I need to wait until google drive finishes processing then proceed with the code, I am also using PHP.

any help is very much appreciated.

```
        $permission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
        //$permission->setValue( 'me' );  //if i uncomment this i get error that method setvalue does not exist
        $permission->setRole( 'reader' );
        $permission->setType( 'anyone' );
        try {
           $a = $service->permissions->create($result->getId(), $permission);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        echo $publicOriginallink = "https://drive.google.com/file/d/".$result->getId()."/view";
```

even after executing this the status of the file does not change and still stays private

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Permission::setValue()

Comment: Welcome to stack please edit your question include your code and describe any issues you are having with your current solution.

Comment: @DaImTo hello i have added the method i tried recebtly to try and make the file public but did not work for me

Comment: What was the error.

Comment: if i uncomment setvalue i get Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Google_Service_Drive_Permission::setValue() but if i remove it goes without any error but when i check file i still find it private not public

Comment: Have you checked the documentation Value is not a parameter for Drive permission.  How do you know the file is not public, have you tried doing a permissions.list on the file to see what was created?

Comment: i tried manually via another account and browser can you please let me know the correct code to make a file public for anyone with link to view via the file id ?

Comment: A file id can not be used in a link to a google drive file.   You wold need to use the webview link in the file response.

Comment: i check manually by going to my google drive as for generating a link i think it is like this 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/idhere/view

Comment: A file id can not be used in a link to a google drive file. You wold need to use the webview link in the file response.     do a file.get find the webviewlink

Comment: i have found a workaround for this by setting the parent folder to public it makes all files inside as public by default however i would still prefer enabling it myself, the last problem i have now is after uploading a video it usually goes to processing how do i know when its done via php ?

Comment: `If the request succeeds, the server returns the HTTP 200 OK status code along with the file's metadata` Is that what you meant? Once you get the file data, it is uploaded.